# how to handle arguments in auxiliary constructors before calling primary one?

Tags: scala, constructor

I'm new to Scala and still face some newbie(?) issues.

So I have a class called `Transaction` whose primary constructor has 5 arguments. The thing is that I'm trying to write a 1-argument constructor with a String argument so it fetches the other arguments from it and calls the primary constructor with them (it basically parses the string).

I have read that the first call inside an auxiliary constructor must be to the primary constructor, then how I am supposed to call it with no useful data? What other approach would exist to solve this issue?

Here I paste the class code and the failing constructor:

```
class Transaction(srcIp: String, dstIp: String, var srcPort: Int, var dstPort: Int, _protocol: String) {
  def this(t_str: String) = {
    val t_arr = t_str.split(',')
    this(t_arr(1), t_arr(2), t_arr(3).toInt, t_arr(4).toInt, t_arr(5))
  }
  //primary constructor, private variables, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala constructor overloading must necessarily (and only) call another constructor, primary or auxiliary. This is because default arguments in Scala didn't enter the language until Scala 2.8.

If you want to "parse" your string that way, you can create a companion object (see [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)) and overload the `apply` method to call the primary constructor (or any of the overloaded auxiliary constructors).